# New Android Design Library bug with AppBarLayout and Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I am using the new Android Design Library based on this example [chrisbanes/cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) in github and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

I have run the example and I am having problems with Toolbar inside CheeseDetailActivity. The toolbar isnt shown as it should. Have a look at the images below:

At first image you can see the toolbar isn't shown correctly.

[image]

At the second image you can see that the toolbar is shown correctly but the notification bar is white. This happens because I removed from actiivty_detail.xml `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

[image]

I think that `fitsSystemWindows` should be true and the problem is related with `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` but I don't have any idea how I can fix this problem. I tried with `marginTop` with the same height as `notificationBar` but it didn't work.

Any suggestion is appreciated :)

This is a part of the `activity_detail.xml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: where did you set the `app:layout_behavior`?

Comment: I didn't show all the xml but you can find it here: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml

Comment: [CoordinatorLayout#setStatusBarBackgroundColor(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html#setStatusBarBackgroundColor(int))

Comment: I don't want to change status bar color, I want it to look like this: https://youtu.be/32i7ot0y78U?t=4m13s

Comment: I see. `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on `AppBarLayout` because you want it behind status bar and `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` on `Toolbar` because you don't.

Comment: @EugenPechanec it doesn't work, i have tried that already, and i have also noticed that if you put the same exact layout inside of viewpager, the nestedScrollView will always has some sort of paddingTop unless if you touch it, then it will remove that, i tried requestLayout, buildLayer, invalidate and nothing worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your *Design Library* with New Version **build.gradle** file in **app** folder like:

> compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'

As Updated in [+AndroidDevelopers](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/XTtNCPviwpj)

I got output like:

[image]

It will helps you.

Thanks :)

Comment: I haven't test it but that must be the solution :)

Comment: The android support design library version 22.2.1 did not solve the issue for me. I had troubles again on devices running Android 5.0. I had to update to 23.1.0. It works now

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this is a bug in `com.android.support:design:22.2.0`.
It will be fixed, it's marked as future release. So lets hope it will be soon.
Links with issues: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175240
and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175069

Comment: Lets hope they fix it quickly :)

Comment: @PratikButani They have made an update according to this post https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/XTtNCPviwpj I havent checked yet if it fixes this problem

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem put in style with windowActionBar and windowNoTitle and decided my problem.

```
<style name="AppTheme.base" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working workaround for API 21:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    marginResult = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(getString(R.string.identifier_status_bar_height), getString(R.string.identifier_dimen), getString(R.string.identifier_android));    
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        marginResult = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)*2;
     }
    CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams params = (CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams) mToolbar.getLayoutParams();
    params.topMargin -= marginResult;
    mToolbar.setLayoutParams(params);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, my toolbar was displaying wrong on API level greater than 21. I was using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar as supportActionBar() and below content is in fragment, see pictures:
[on aplication start, toolbar is displaying wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiFNW.png)
and [when i colapse android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout, the picture is not hidden completely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9DIm.png)

I resolved this when i added android:fitsSystemWindows="true" attribute to the root element of view where Toolbar is located.

Now:
[toolbar is displaying normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRCGb.png) and 
[picture is hidden completely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuLjr.png)