# Strange behavior with CoordinatorLayout, AppbarLayout and SwipeRefreshView

Tags: android, android-toolbar, coordinator-layout

I'm trying to use the new Android Support Design Library, but I've encountered a strange behavior (maybe it's not so strange) with CoordinatorLayout having as children a AppBarLayout and a SwipeRefreshView: in fact, when I swipe to up the SwipeRefreshView the AppbarLayout hides the Toolbar, even the first one is empty.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfgcnh3rloeva93/issue.gif?dl=0

Here I posted the layout and a GIF to show this behavior.
Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541409/coordinatorlayoutappbarlayout-does-not-draw-toolbar-properly