# Translucent/Transparent status bar + CoordinatorLayout + Toolbar + Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have following setup:

- I'm using AppCompat
- MainActivity, that holds a fragment and has a toolbar, that's hiding when scrolling down
- `Fragment` with `RecyclerView`
- all views that should fit the screen have the according `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the xml layout

The problem is, I can't get the statusbar transparent in this case. What I do is following:

1. Create the activity and call setContent
2. Then I try to adjust the activity to programmatically get a translucent toolbar like following:

   ```
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
   public void themeNavAndStatusBar(Activity activity)
   {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
           return;

       Window w = activity.getWindow();
       w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
       w.setFlags(
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
       w.setFlags(
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
       w.setNavigationBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

       w.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
   }
   ```
3. Replace the placeholder in the activity (`@+id/frame_container`) with the fragment

The statusbar is solid colored in this case, and the views are not drawn underneath it... Why?

**What I want**

I want a toolbar, that is scrolled of the screen and hiding completely while the content underneath this toolbar should fitScreen and be drawn behind the transparent nav bar.

**Layouts**

Here's my main activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/clMain"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="?attr/main_background_color"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@null"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="?actionBarThemeStyle"
            app:popupTheme="?actionBarPopupThemeStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivToolbarDataSource"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvToolbarTitle"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                        android:theme="?actionBarThemeStyle"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvToolbarSubTitle"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
                    android:theme="?actionBarThemeStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>



        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <!-- BUG: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541409/coordinatorlayoutappbarlayout-does-not-draw-toolbar-properly -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_local_offer_white_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="com.test.classes.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is my fragment, that will be placed in the main activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/srlImages"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvImages"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmpty"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT - Screenshots**

I use a light/dark base theme and theme everything by hand (because the user can select any color as primary/accent color), so don't mind that the toolbar is white (it's the default's theme background color and primary color). I added a black border as well so that you see where the activity ends...

- First Screenshot: Shows the toolbar, nothing is scrolled
- Second Screenshot: I just started scrolling => the toolbar now should scroll away
- Third Screenshot: the main content should now scroll underneath the nav bar...

In the end, I'll of course make the toolbar and navbar semi transparent for a better visual effect...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you post some image? You should probably set fitsSystemWindows to false to the CoordinatorLayout (at least).

Comment: I added screenshots to show the problem...

Comment: Set fitsSystemWindows to false to the CoordinatorLayout and to the frame_container .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the reason was not that it did not work per se, but that I use the material drawer library from Mike Penz and this library does use fullscreen + offset + custom background behind the toolbar so I had to solve the problem respecting that special setup...

I'll reward the points to the in my opinion most informative answer though...

Comment: v5.0.0 will stop to do the offset etc. It will use platform defaults and depdend on the `fitsSystemWindows` flag. There is also the CollapsingToolbar example https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/CollapsingToolbarActivity.java

Answer (score 70):

**tl;dr** Set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` at least to the root `CoordinatorLayout` and to the inner fragment container, `@frame_container`.

This might not be the final solution (i.e. there might be other `fitsSystemWindows` to change) so tell me if you have any problems.

**why**

When it comes to status bar, I think of `fitsSystemWindows` like so:

- `fitsSystemWindows="false"` : draws the view normally, **under** the status bar because of the window flags you have set.
- `fitsSystemWindows="true"`  : draws the view normally, **under** the status bar because of the window flags you have set, but **adds a top padding** so that content is drawn below the status bar and they don't overlap.

In fact, in my opinion, the white you see is not the status bar color, but rather your `CoordinatorLayout` background. That is due to `fitsSystemWindows="true"` on the coordinator: it draws the background to the whole window, but adds top padding to the content so inner views are not covered by status bar.

This is not what you want. Your inner content **must** be covered by the status bar, and so you have to set `fitsSystemWindows="false"` to the coordinator (so it won't apply top padding) and probably to the content itself.

Once you get how it works, <strike>it is easy to debug and achieve the effect you are looking for</strike>. *Actually, it is not. Years pass, but I still spend hours trying to figure out the right fitsSystemWindows combination, because most Views (in the support libraries at least) override the default behavior that I stated above, in ways that are mostly not intuitive. See [this post](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.7qzcybpxi) for a small guide on how to use it.*

Comment: the problem with `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` is that the toolbar too is now behind the status bar.

Comment: "In fact, in my opinion, the white you see is not the status bar color, but rather your CoordinatorLayout background." THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: @HammadNasir I think the better way is to set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and in `coordinateLayout` set `app:statusBarBackground="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: please see this answer too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47906087/2201814

Answer (score 13):

Edit your styles.xml (v21) , add the following style

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Home" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

</style>
```

You can change parent theme as per your liking, but now declare this theme in your AndroidManifest.xml file for a particular activity like this :

```
 <activity
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Home"
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

This will let your content visible under the transparent actionbar.

Now use the following to align your toolbar below the StatusBar properly, call this in your oncreate:

```
 toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
```

Get statusbar height using following :

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Remove the following from your coordinator layout tags :

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Now in order to collapse your toolbar or hide it you may refer to [this tutorial](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

Make sure you are using following version of design support library, as it is bug free :

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. I rewrote aligning a ToolBar below a StatusBar, adding not only padding, but also a height to the ToolBar. I mean toolbar.getLayoutParams().height += getStatusBarHeight();

Comment: Also, AppBarLayout.LayoutParams lp = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams(); lp.topMargin += getStatusBarHeight();

Answer (score 5):

After reading your descriptions about your question, I thought styles of **Google Photos** matches your requirement.

OK, there are just some tips for your question. After my test, it works.

- If you want to show content behind status bar, you need add `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` into your
  style when Android version level is larger than 19(namely **KitKat**)
- If you want to show content behind navigation bar, you need add
  `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>` into your
  style when Android version level is larger than 19(namely **KitKat**)
- If you want to hide `Toolbar` smoothly when content is scrolled up
  and to show `Toolbar` smoothly when content is scrolled down, you
  need to add `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` into your
  `Toolbar`'s attributes based on your current codes.Of course, you
  need coordinate `Toolbar` with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`
  `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: Didn't you mix up status and navigation bar in the descriptive text?

Comment: What did I mix up?

Comment: @SilentKnight, "If you want to show content behind status bar" and "android:windowTranslucentNavigation". Maybe you have mixed a description. But thanks, it helps.

Answer (score 3):

as some users said, by setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`, the layout **overlapped** below `statusbar`.

I solved it by setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and in `CoordinatorLayout` tag setting `app:statusBarBackground="@android:color/transparent"`.

Comment: Oh, thanks man! I've spent half of a day, finding out, why my fragment adds status bar additional height.

Comment: Amazing finding ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my solution was add **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"** to the **DrawerLayout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"> 

....

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, it hasn't helped me. See above answers, they may help.

Answer (score 0):

I had relevant issues depend on android:fitsSystemWindows setting.
Once false:
Snacks was drawn under the Navigation bar
Once true:
Status bar had none transparent background

Solution was really simple...
Just to add android:layout_marginBottom="48dp". to CoordinatorLayout like that:

```
just to add <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
android:layout_marginBottom="48dp">
```

Theoretically Navigation bar should have fixed size "48dp", but in future releases potentially it may change (like Status bar got slimmer by 1dp in Marshmallow), so I wouldn't rely on fixed size.
Better additionally get it and apply on run time.

If You are using Google Map like me You may want to know ActionBar/Toolbar size and the navigation bar in run time:

in onCreate use this code:

```
            final TypedArray styledAttributes = MapsActivity.this.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                new int[]{android.R.attr.actionBarSize});
        mToolbarHeight = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
        styledAttributes.recycle();
        // translucent bars code. Will not fire below Lollipop
        // Ask NavigationBar Height
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout),
                new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() { // setContentView() must be fired already
                    @Override
                    public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
                        statusBar = insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop(); // You may also need this value
                        mNavBarHeight = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
                        if (mMap != null)
                            mMap.setPadding(0, mToolbarHeight, 0, mNavBarHeight);
                        // else will be set in onMapReady()
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
                        editor
                                .putInt(NAVBAR_HEIGHT_KEY, mNavBarHeight)
                                .commit(); // Save the results in flash memory and run the code just once on app first run instead of doing it every run
                        return insets;
                    }
                }
        );
```

And what's important. If You got some additional layers like drawer etc put them encapsulating the CoordinatorLayout inside rather than outside as otherwise it will make other views inside shorter by the marginBottom

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to have the toolbar have the same color as the status bar, by getting the status bar transparent:

**build.gradle**

```
...
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

````
**ScrollingActivity.kt**
```kt
class ScrollingActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_scrolling) {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }
}
````

**activity_scrolling.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f00" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin" android:text="@string/large_text" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.lb.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ScrollingActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the following code to your theme, this code will make the status bar transparent:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
```

Additionally, add scroll behavior to your top app bar. The following example shows the top app bar disappearing upon scrolling up, and appearing upon scrolling down:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
...>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        ...
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
 ...
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add this code to AppBarLayout:

```
 app:liftOnScroll="true"
```

Then update your "app:layout_scrollFlags" in your toolbar:

```
  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
```

This will work, I am pretty sure.