# Transparent Status Bar - Coordinate Layout

Tags: android

I want to make my status bar transparent . I followed the following code practices but all in vain . I used the code from Android Authority tutorial . Importing their files works perfectly but when I am using the same code in my project it is not working at all .

Style v21

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Activity -

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.plumbum.aapu.household.Hello">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"

            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:title="Hello">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/morning_1"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="@string/large_text"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have no idea what wrong I am doing . help !!

Comment: Use `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`  in style.

Comment: Both translucent and transparent are not working it is still displaying primaryDarkColor instead of the image below it

Comment: Link to the tutorial - http://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/

Comment: Please refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907615/android-transparent-status-bar-and-actionbar/29907616#29907616

Comment: Already tried before. Not helping

Comment: try my answer also it will works perfectly @DawnImpulse

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47906087/2201814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->      
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Adding parent theme is not helping

Comment: you have not add parent in style tag. Try to do, It is working for me.