# Transparent status bar overlaps action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, statusbar, transparent

**Actual result**: The status bar appears over the action bar `Toolbar` and the `MenuItem` inside the action bar is cut off. Note: "Test" is the action bar's `title`.

[image: JankActionBar]

**Expected result**:
The top bound of the action bar `Toolbar` should appear directly below the bottom bound of the status bar and any `MenuItem`s inside the action bar should be completely visible.

**Activity's XML layout:**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The action bar `title` and `MenuItem` are added at runtime.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_bar));
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setTitle("Test");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Before I added `fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the `Toolbar` view, the status bar still overlayed the action bar, but the 'SKIP' `MenuItem` was vertically centered in the action bar, causing it to appear partially underneath the status bar. I expected the `fitsSystemWindows=true` flag to give me my expected result (mentioned above), but it did not. It's as if `fitsSystemWindows="true"` correctly positioned the 'SKIP' button but did not adjust the position of the action bar itself. Anyone know what might be the issue here?

EDIT: I realize that I could remove `fitsSystemWindows="true"` and add a `marginTop="...statusBarHeight"` to the `Toolbar` view, but I am looking for the a cleaner way to solve this.

Comment: can you please share the complete layout file ? and the layout preview image ? I cant see test and skip button code in the layout.

Comment: is this happen to other layout?

Comment: @rahul, maybe Ryan add title and menu item programmatically, not in xml

Comment: @ntaloventi if that is the case I think making a custom toolbar and including it in the layout file will be a good idea. It makes code more cleaner and easy to maintain.

Comment: @rahul, agree with you but base on Ryan layout there is no `test` & `skip button` as you expected

Comment: @Ryan can you share the complete code how are you adding the skip button on the layout and the complete layout preview image ?

Comment: @rahul Just added the code I'm using at runtime to add the title and skip button to the action bar. The layout I shared is the full layout. The rest of the screenshot is just the "image_background" `ImageView`. No other views are below the action bar.

Comment: @Ryan follow this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-Toolbar this might be helpful !

Answer (score 7):

My issue was due to me setting the `Toolbar`'s `layout_height` to `?attr/actionBarSize`. I originally thought that `fitsSystemWindows` repositions the `Toolbar`, but it appears to add a padding instead. So when top padding is added to the `Toolbar`, the `Toolbar`'s contents are pushed down. Since the `Toolbar`'s height is fixed, the contents are pushed below the lower bound of the container. I ended up setting `?attr/actionBarSize` as the value for the `Toolbar`'s `minHeight` attribute to solve this. Below is my updated `Toolbar`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

**Caveat**: This works if you aren't wanting to show anything directly below the action bar since the action bar's height, for one reason or another, is about twice the height that it needs to be to contain a single line of the home icon, title, and/or menu items. If anyone knows a way to achieve a non-overlapping status bar AND a normal size action bar, please share your insight. I would be forever grateful.

[image: HugeActionBar]

**Caveat update**: Okay. So apparently my action bar was receiving extra, bottom padding  equivalent to the height of the navigation bar because I set `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>` on my `Activity`'s theme. I verified this by removing the `windowTranslucentNavigation` attribute. I am testing this on a 7.1 Pixel using Android Support Libraries v25.1.1.

Comment: This solution does not exist for screens that require a normal size action bar with `layout_height` = `?attr/actionBarSize`. I have not found a solution for this. :/

Comment: What helped me to keep status bar translucent (almost same color as toolbar), and toolbar of the right size, was to put all content of activity into coordinator layout in xml.

Comment: I've fought with similar problem for a day, and the only thing what helped me was to set on toolbar android:fitsSystemWindows="false" as suggested in that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856737/490114 Then the size and paddings of toolbar were set correctly

Comment: Thanks, this helpful after a day of searching what the problem was.
The property in the Toolbar android:fitsSystemWindows="true" did the trick. It pushed the toolbar just below the status bar

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your **Toolbar** into **AppBarLayout**.

Like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<AppBarLayout/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using flags to make activity fullscreen and my style is NoActionBar.

If i set `fitsSystemWindows=true` to toolar or parent layout, activity content size changed because of navigation bar and status bar.

I wrapped `ToolBar` with `AppBarLayout` like in [Twinkie_Monkey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380096/13962381) and I set `fitsSystemWindows=true` to `AppBarLayout` and it worked.