# 100% Transparent status bar and navigation bar, but with fitsSystemWindows

Tags: java, android

`FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` was right. But fitsSystemWindows not working at this time. Is there any solution for exactly **100% transparent status bar and navigation bar but fitsSystemWindows works** too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translucent/Transparent status bar + CoordinatorLayout + Toolbar + Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761671/translucent-transparent-status-bar-coordinatorlayout-toolbar-fragment)

Comment: No. The answer is not the same as my question. I want 100% transparent, not a translucent.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.