# How to adjust Toolbar alignment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm looking over design support library examples in the "[Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)" demo of newer components I want to use. On my OnePlus One, the Toolbar is barely off-screen.

[image: DrawerToggle and Menu buttons off top edge of screen.]

I think `CheeseDetailActivity.java`, `activity_detail.xml`, and maybe `styles.xml` are pertinent here but I can't seem to make changes that correct the misalignment.

Comment: FWIW, this was asked [here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540648/new-android-design-library-bug-with-appbarlayout-and-toolbar), with no answer. I'd suggest filing an issue, but the issue tracker is not enabled on that GitHub repo...

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I'll keep an eye on that post too. I tweeted the dev, maybe we'll hear something if he has a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marked fixed for future release in AOSP Issue Tracker [#175069](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175069)