# (Design Support Library) Toolbar items behind the status bar

Tags: android, android-design-library

I am using @chrisbanes design sample:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

the toolbar items appears behind the status bar on Lollipop only.

Please note that the same error shows on the sample, check the first screenshot.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Can you post your layout and your styles.xml?

Comment: Add margin top to 25dp to the `Toolbar`, thats the hight of the status bar.

Comment: @AlexFacciorusso same problem appears on Chrisbanes sample, here is the related files:https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I tried that trick and it didn't work, also I tried to apply the top margin on the collapsing toolbar with no success also.

Comment: @MahdiHijazi same problem with Chris Banes' project without changing anything? Very strange, because I'm using it with no problems…

Comment: Any solution for above issue I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in `com.android.support:design:22.2.0`. It's marked as future release, so we'll probably see a fix soon. Links with issues:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175240
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175069

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30574944/2767703).